# Regex not allow more than 3 same characters and at least 3 words

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
/^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+|([a-z])\1\1\1/
```

This successfully checks if I have at least 3 words, but also validates if I have more than 3 same characters.

Need to accomplish at least 3 words and not have more than 3 consecutive characters on the row. Don't know much about regex syntax unfortunately.

From what I understand I need to combine the above and also make the second with a negative lookahead. Can someone help?

**Valid examples:**

*I like burgers*

*I like burgers a lot*

*Nice commercial spot*

**Invalid examples:**

*I*

*I like*

*I like burgeeeers*

Comment: You should add some examples of valid and invalid subjetcs with this pattern, and add examples of what should be and what shouldn't be validated. The result you try to obtain is unclear.

Comment: You are right @Antwane , i added some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using negative lookahead you can do:

```
/^(?!.*?([A-Za-z])\1{3})\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+/m
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT5gW8/5)

`(?!.*?([A-Za-z])\1{3})` is a negative lookahead to make sure same letter is not repeated more than 3 times (check my demo).

Comment: Yeap! nailed it.Thanks